# Set the menu over div (z-index)

Tags: css

I have example page to describe my problem: https://www.suale.it/Shelter/app/app/index.html
if you try to open the menu, and try to click between "list" and "new ads", you will click over the dropdown search menu

As you can see, i've set the z-index to 1 for the menu, and 0 for the search DIV, but i didnt resolve the problem
here my result:
[image]

```js
$("div[data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>



  <body>

    <!--   <input type=button onclick="clickButton()" value="prova">-->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">


  <div  id="menuPanel"   class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" >
            <h4>Menu</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF" >List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF" >New Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF" >Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF" >Login</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF" >Your Ads</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"  onclick='Website2APK.rateUs();'>Rate us</a></li>               
            </ul>
            <p></p>
            <img src="img/head2.jpg" />
        </div> 
        
        
        
        
        
               <div id="divFilter"  >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Category</b></td>
                        <td><b>Type</b></td>
                        <td><b>Distance Km</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="cbbSearchCategory" onchange="ScaricadatiEavvia();"></select></td><!---->
                        <td>
                            <select id="cbbSearchType" onchange="ScaricadatiEavvia();"></select></td><!---->
                         <!-- <td>
                          <select id="cbbSearchRace" onchange="ScaricadatiEavvia();">
                                <option value=""></option>
                            </select>
                        </td>-->
                        <td>
                            <select id="cbbSearchKM" class="form-control" onchange="ScaricadatiEavvia();">
                              <!-- <option value=""></option>  <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>-->
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>                               
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                <option value="500">500</option>
                                <option value="" selected>2000</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                          <!-- <td>
                                <input type="button" id="btn2"  onclick="ScaricadatiEavvia();" value="Filter"/>-->
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>      
              </body>
```

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/ Your live example doesn’t seem to reproduce the problem (any more?), at least not when I test this in chrome. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi there, i've seen, it depends on the screen resolution, now ill try to put some HTML code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.ui-panel{
    z-index:999 !important
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-select .ui-btn select {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Can you try this.